# ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError in BooksController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

```
            I am new to ruby as well as rails, now I am developing an application using Rails4 and Eclipse IDE..the application is Library application the functionalists are new,create a book,show,list,delete and edit book etc.
            I enter in the browser http://127.0.0.1:3000/books/new it shows a form with fields title,price,subject and description and create button when I clicked the button its showing the following error
            ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError in BooksController#create
            ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError

              def create
                  @book = Book.new(params[:book])--------it is line no 13
                  if @book.save
                        redirect_to :action => 'list'
             ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError (ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError):
              app/controllers/books_controller.rb:13:in `create'


              Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (0.0ms).....

            It having two models
            book.rb
            class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
                belongs_to :subject
               validates_presence_of :title
              validates_numericality_of :price, :message=>"Error Message"
            end
            subject.rb
            class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
                has_many :books
            end
            the controller is 
            books_controller.rb

            class BooksController < ApplicationController
               def list
                  @books = Book.find(:all)
               end
               def show
                  @book = Book.find(params[:id])
               end
               def new
                  @book = Book.new
                  @subjects = Subject.find(:all)
               end
               def create
                  @book = Book.new(params[:book])
                  if @book.save
                        redirect_to :action => 'list'
                  else
                        @subjects = Subject.find(:all)
                        render :action => 'new'
                  end
               end
               private 
               def book_params
               params.require(:book).permit(:Title,:Price,:Subject,:Description)
               end

                  def edit
                  @book = Book.find(params[:id])
                  @subjects = Subject.find(:all)
               end
               def update
                  @book = Book.find(params[:id])
                  if @book.update_attributes(params[:book])
                     redirect_to :action => 'show', :id => @book
                  else
                     @subjects = Subject.find(:all)
                     render :action => 'edit'
                  end
               end
               def delete
                  Book.find(params[:id]).destroy
                  redirect_to :action => 'list'
               end
               def show_subjects
                  @subject = Subject.find(params[:id])
               end
            end
            route file is
            routes.rb
            LibrarayWebApplication::Application.routes.draw do
                get 'books/new'
                post 'books/create'
              get 'books/list'
               get 'books/show'
              get 'books/edit'
             get 'books/show_subjects'
            end
            and the view file is 

            new.erb
            <h1>Add new book</h1>
            <%= form_tag :action => 'create' %>
            <p><label for="book_title">Title</label>:
            <%= text_field 'book', 'title' %></p>
            <p><label for="book_price">Price</label>:
            <%= text_field 'book', 'price' %></p>
            <p><label for="book_subject">Subject</label>:
            <%= collection_select(:book,:subject_id,@subjects,:id,:name) %></p>
            <p><label for="book_description">Description</label><br/>
            <%= text_area 'book', 'description' %></p>
            <%= submit_tag "Create" %>
            <%= link_to 'Back', {:action => 'list'} %>
```

the database contains the tables with fields but it does not storing the data rather its showing the error as  I am new to this its taking me a lots of time and it shows a form with fields title,price,subject and description and create button when I clicked the button its showing the following error

```
            migration files are
            migrations are created the both the tables.

                 20140318084539_books.rb 
        #its created the books table in the mysql database

                    class Books < ActiveRecord::Migration
                     def self.up
                         create_table :books do |t|
                      t.column :title, :string, :limit => 32, :null => false
                      t.column :price, :float
                      t.column :subject_id, :integer
                      t.column :description, :text
                      t.column :created_at, :timestamp
                         end
                      end

                      def self.down
                        drop_table :books
                      end
                    end

                20140318084609_subjects.rb
            #it is created the subjects table in the database
                    class Subjects < ActiveRecord::Migration
                      def self.up
                          create_table :subjects do |t|
                           t.column :name, :string

                        Subject.create :name => "Physics"
                        Subject.create :name => "Mathematics"
                        end
                      def self.down
                          drop_table :subjects
                      end  end

I am unable to solve this issue
       the following code will displays the list of subjects when accessing the method
    I am unable to solve this issue
    I used the Strong Parameters in books_controller.rb file
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def book_params
  params.require(:book).permit(:title,:price,:subject,:description)
end


def create
  @book = Book.new(book_params)
  if @book.save
       redirect_to :action => 'list'
   else
       @subjects = Subject.find(:all)
       render :action => 'new'
   end
 end
```